# What are the big major drawbacks porting a wpf LOB to silverlight 4

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I am thinking about porting my alpha WPF MVVM application to silverlight.

I do not use 3D its a LOB ;-)

What I promise myself from the conversion is to get more customers in the end (Mac/nix user do not pay well ;P).

1.) At the moment I am using sqlite as database. Is it possible, that I can access the sqlite file on the harddisk of my user to read/save data? (on User dir its possible but access an USB stick ?)

2.) Is there anything concerning MVVM silverlight can not handle?

3.) Does SEO work well with Silverlight 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.) At the moment I am using sqlite as database. Is it possible, that I can access the sqlite file on the harddisk of my user to read/save data? (on User dir its possible but access an USB stick ?)

If you want to use a local database then you'll either need to install your Silverlight application on the local machine as a full trust application or use a database that installs into [Isolated Storage](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/isolatedstorage/) like SiaqoDb (as suggested by @Shawn Mclean). You won't be able to access a USB stick.

When run in a browser across the net it has limited access to the local hard drive for security reasons. If you're doing this you might as well stick with WPF.

> 2.) Is there anything concerning MVVM silverlight can not handle?

You can use [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648611.aspx) to develop MVVM applications for Silverlight as well as WPF.

> 3.) Does SEO work well with Silverlight 4?

I don't know a great deal about this, but Silverlight can be viewed as Microsoft's version of Flash so it will probably have the same SEO issues as Flash. The code is compiled and delivered to the client in binary form, so unless you split your application across multiple HTML/ASP.NET pages there won't be anything for Google to index. Apparently Flash does support SEO, but I haven't looked into SEO and Silverlight.

Comment: to 1.) does that mean I need a webhoster which allows me to install my webapp on his server with "full rights" ?

Comment: @Lisa - no. Serving a Silverlight app across the network is like serving a Flash application. The application runs on the client machine, but has limited access to the hard drive.

Comment: So "I" actually the user has to install the app on his machine? (because of the full trust)?) Never tried a flash app.

Comment: @Lisa - if you are serving the application across the internet then your users don't have to install it - just the Silverlight runtime.

Comment: I suggest using one of those silverlight databases that runs in IsolatedStorage. Like SiaqoDb.

Comment: @ChrisF I would like to mark your solution as OK, but would you please reread question 1.)  "Is it possible, that I can access the sqlite file on the harddisk of my user to read/save data? (on User dir its possible but access an USB stick ?)" and then answer on this question?

Comment: @ChrisF judging this link: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/whitepapers/seo-for-silverlight/ Silverlight SEO works better than flash, but anyway, when my user can not access their USB stick for the database Silverlight is a no-go for me.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.) At the moment I am using sqlite as database. Is it possible, that I can access the sqlite file on the harddisk of my user to read/save data? (on User dir its possible but access an USB stick ?)

The basic principal of Silverlight is centralised data over services. You can have local data, but that is not as useful generally compared to a central storage. You then have no worries about full trust as it will run in any Silverlight browser.

You *can* use SQLLite on your server, however the best *free* database option we have found is SQL Service Express 2008 R2.

You can access USB, but it requires both OOB, Full Trust and a custom COM automation object installed on the client (so Windows only). *Basically forget local USB storage and support downloads instead, if local copies are needed.*

> 2.) Is there anything concerning MVVM silverlight can not handle?

Bindings in Silverlight 4 are now very similar to those in WFP. Accessing parent elements from templates is a little more difficult, but most *simple* bindings are the same.

> 3.) Does SEO work well with Silverlight 4?

First ensure that you provide a sitemap for the searchengines. That should map to all content pages.

Provide a parallel ASP.Net website to publish your content for the search engines to read. This is now quite easy with RIA services as an ASP.Net website can consume a RIA service just like any other WCF service.

Make good use of headers, meta tags, titles, human-readable urls to include relevant keywords.